# Quanteda Textfile Twitter JSON Error Reading

Tags: json, r, text, quanteda

I am trying to use Quanteda's textfile wrapper to read in the JSON at the following [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B02KoGnAn1VOLXlNbF9HN3lHTUE):

My code is the following:

```
textfile("20070101-20080214_ehfdpezgqg_2007_01_01_00_00_activities.json",
     textField = "body")
```

But when I run this I obtain the following error, despite the linked file being a Twitter JSON.

```
Error in data.table::rbindlist(lapply(lines, function(x)     jsonlite::fromJSON(x,  : 
  Column 3 of item 1 is length 19, inconsistent with first column of that    item which is length 1. rbind/rbindlist doesn't recycle as it already expects     each item to be a uniform list, data.frame or data.table
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
Doesn't look like Tweets json file, trying general JSON
2: In if (e == paste("There is no field called", textField, "in file",  :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In value[[3L]](cond) :
File doesn't contain a single valid JSON object, trying line-delimited json
```

I have read the documentation for Quanteda and it is a little opaque about what is going on here. I can read this file in using the regular R JSON readers, but I want to read it in "the Quanteda way".

Comment: can you add a portion of your JSON file so that others can reproduce your issue?

Comment: The JSON file is linked.

Comment: I'm not keen on downloading from unknown google.drive links

Comment: And, in the future, what if the link breaks?

Comment: Apparently, I cannot even edit my own posts on StackOverflow because I don't have the privilege to do so. Anyway, you should try opening the Google Drive link above (it's a one-line JSON) with a third party app (e.g. Notepad, Sublime Text) and resaving it.

Comment: Well, what is the preferred method of sharing?

Comment: Can you use your one line of JSON in `data.table::rbindlist(jsonlite::fromJSON(yourLine))`, as this is the bit that is causing the error

Comment: When I do so, I obtain the following error:

Comment: "Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  parse error: trailing garbage
          nks \"I'm\"","tag":null}]}}  {"info":{"message":"Replay Requ
                     (right here) ------^"

Comment: We are about to phase out `textfile()` since we've created a new package just for reading text data, called [**readtext**](http://github.com/kbenoit/readtext). Could you install that from GitHub and try it?

Comment: Yes, also I've allowed you access to the JSON upon which the package breaks.

Comment: I can report similar errors on the readtext package.

Comment: Please file an issue at https://github.com/kbenoit/readtext/issues